# Need to add a footnote in between texts and the next text should be appeared in the same line not in the next line in Apache poi

Tags: apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am trying to create a a paragraph with continuous text .I am not being able to add a footnote in between 
in between a continuous paragraph, either it got added at the last or i need to create another paragraph for the next sentences.
[image: Attached screesnhot for the paragrapgh]
 1. Below is the snippet for the code attached for the explaination :

```
public class WordBuilder1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("The table:");
        createFootNote(document);
        createParagraph(document, "This is the second sentence", 12, ParagraphAlignment.LEFT, false, UnderlinePatterns.NONE);
        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
        if (sectPr == null) sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
        pageSz.setOrient(STPageOrientation.PORTRAIT);
        pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(11900)); //12240 Twips = 12240/20 = 612 pt = 612/72 = 8.5"
        pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(16840)); //15840 Twips = 15840/20 = 792 pt = 792/72 = 11"

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\mishrne\\example.docx");
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
    }

    private static void createFootNote(XWPFDocument document) {
        XWPFRun run = document.createParagraph().createRun();
        run.setText("This is a footnote first line");
        run.setFontFamily(TIMES_NEW_ROMAN);
        run.setFontSize(12);
        if (document.getFootnotes().isEmpty()) {
            document.createFootnotes();
        }
        prepareFootNotes(document, FOOTNOTE_TEXT);
        // if styles dont already exist then create them
        if (document.getStyles() == null) {
            document.createStyles();
        }
        prepareFooterStyle(document);
    }

    //create paragraph
    private static void createParagraph(XWPFDocument document, String text, int fontSize, ParagraphAlignment paragraphAlignment, boolean isBold, UnderlinePatterns single) {
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        if (paragraphAlignment != null) {
            paragraph.setAlignment(paragraphAlignment);
        }
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText(text);
        run.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
        run.setFontSize(fontSize);
        run.setUnderline(single);
        run.setBold(isBold);
    }

    private static void prepareFootNotes(XWPFDocument document, String footnotesText) {
        // add footnote
        CTFtnEdn ctfInstance = CTFtnEdn.Factory.newInstance();
        BigInteger id = new BigInteger("1");
        ctfInstance.setId(id);
        CTP ctp = ctfInstance.addNewP();
        ctp.addNewPPr().addNewPStyle().setVal("FootnoteText");
        CTR ctr = ctp.addNewR();
        ctr.addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
        ctr.addNewFootnoteRef();
        CTText cttext = ctp.addNewR().addNewT();
        cttext.setStringValue(footnotesText);
        cttext.setSpace(SpaceAttribute.Space.PRESERVE);
        // add footnote to document
        document.addFootnote(ctfInstance);
        ctr = document.getParagraphArray(1).getCTP().addNewR();
        ctr.addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
        ctr.addNewFootnoteReference().setId(id);
    }

    private static void prepareFooterStyle(XWPFDocument document) {
        CTStyle style = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
        style.setStyleId("FootnoteReference");
        style.setType(STStyleType.CHARACTER);
        style.addNewName().setVal("footnote reference");
        style.addNewBasedOn().setVal("DefaultParagraphFont");
        style.addNewUiPriority().setVal(new BigInteger("99"));
        style.addNewSemiHidden();
        style.addNewUnhideWhenUsed();
        style.addNewRPr().addNewVertAlign().setVal(STVerticalAlignRun.SUPERSCRIPT);

        // add style
        document.getStyles().addStyle(new XWPFStyle(style));
        style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
        CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
        indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(100));
        style.setStyleId("FootnoteText");
        style.addNewName().setVal("footnote text");
        style.addNewBasedOn().setVal("Normal");
        style.addNewLink().setVal("FootnoteTextChar");
        style.addNewUiPriority().setVal(new BigInteger("99"));
        style.addNewSemiHidden();
        style.addNewUnhideWhenUsed();
        CTRPr rpr = style.addNewRPr();

        rpr.addNewSz().setVal(new BigInteger("20"));
        rpr.addNewSzCs().setVal(new BigInteger("20"));

        // add style
        document.getStyles().addStyle(new XWPFStyle(style));
    }

    private static void setHeaderRowforSingleCell(XWPFTableCell cell, String text) {
        XWPFParagraph tempParagraph = cell.getParagraphs().get(0);
        tempParagraph.setIndentationLeft(100);
        tempParagraph.setIndentationRight(100);
        tempParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
        tempParagraph.setSpacingAfter(50);
        XWPFRun tempRun = tempParagraph.createRun();
        tempRun.setFontSize(10);
        tempRun.setText(text);
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
    }}
```

Comment: Too much code is just as unhelpful as no code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then reduce the provided code to only show the problem you wants solving now.

Comment: My problem here is I want to create a paragraph of sentences and I need to add the footnote in middle of the paragraph . What approach i should follow ? Because when i am trying to create a paragraph and set the footnote ,the footnote is always getting attached to the end of the paragraph  not in the middle .The above code shows my second approach where i created 2 separate paragraph,so that the footnote should appear in the middle not at end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Word` creating a footnote needs two parts. First creating the footnote on document level. Second attaching the footnote reference to a text run.

The following approach provides a method `BigInteger createFootnote(XWPFDocument document, String footnoteText)` for creating a footnote on document level. It returns the footnote identifier to be usable as footnote reference then. The attaching the footnote reference to an text run can be done then using `run.getCTR().addNewFootnoteReference().setId(footnoteId);` where `run` is a `XWPFRun`.

If the need is formatting the footnote references, as superscript for example, then `Word` itself creates a special character style for this. This also needs two parts. First create the style on document level:

```
XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(CTStyle.Factory.newInstance(), styles);
style.getCTStyle().setType(STStyleType.CHARACTER);
style.getCTStyle().setStyleId("FootnoteReference");
style.getCTStyle().addNewRPr().addNewVertAlign().setVal(STVerticalAlignRun.SUPERSCRIPT);
styles.addStyle(style);
```

Then apply this style to the text runs:

```
run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
```

For this, the footnote references must be in their own text runs.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFtnEdn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyle;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STStyleType;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVerticalAlignRun;

public class CreateWordFootnotes {

 static BigInteger createFootnote(XWPFDocument document, String footnoteText) {
  XWPFFootnotes footnotes = document.createFootnotes();
  CTFtnEdn ctFtnEdn = CTFtnEdn.Factory.newInstance();
  BigInteger footnoteId = BigInteger.valueOf(footnotes.getFootnotesList().size());
  ctFtnEdn.setId(footnoteId);
  XWPFFootnote footnote = footnotes.addFootnote(ctFtnEdn);
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = footnote.addNewParagraph(CTP.Factory.newInstance());
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.getCTR().addNewFootnoteRef(); 
  run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(footnoteText);
  return footnoteId;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
  XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(CTStyle.Factory.newInstance(), styles);
  style.getCTStyle().setType(STStyleType.CHARACTER);
  style.getCTStyle().setStyleId("FootnoteReference");
  style.getCTStyle().addNewRPr().addNewVertAlign().setVal(STVerticalAlignRun.SUPERSCRIPT);
  styles.addStyle(style);

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The text");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is the text run having the first footnote");
  String footnoteText = "The content of the first footnote.";
  BigInteger footnoteId  = createFootnote(document, footnoteText);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
  run.getCTR().addNewFootnoteReference().setId(footnoteId);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" further text comes here and a second footnote");
  footnoteText = "The content of the second footnote.";
  footnoteId  = createFootnote(document, footnoteText);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference");
  run.getCTR().addNewFootnoteReference().setId(footnoteId);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" and now the paragraph ends here.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordFootnotes.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

The code needs the full jar of all of the schemas ooxml-schemas or poi-ooxml-full as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025.

---

Using `apache poi 5.x` it must be

```
...
//import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVerticalAlignRun;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STVerticalAlignRun;
...
```

Comment: How can i set the styles for the integer added , i tried with  style.addNewRPr().addNewVertAlign().setVal(STVerticalAlignRun.SUPERSCRIPT); and it is appended to footnoteText

Comment: @Neha Mishra: See my supplements.